# Assess whether a data set is Poisson using a variance test

Tags: r, self-study, variance, poisson-distribution

As the title says, i'm not sure how a variance test determines that a data set is Poisson.

I've attempted the question and have come up with the following:

```
> c <-c(19, 17, 12, 16, 25, 25, 14, 14, 22, 14, 13, 18,17, 15, 16, 26, 17, 
18, 20, 12)

var(c)
[1] 18.05263

mean(c)
[1] 17.5
```

How does a variance test show that a data set could be Poisson?

Comment: I don't see you conducting a hypothesis test there ...

Comment: I don't think the question asks for hypothesis test. I believe that all you have to say is that since the variance and mean are very close to each other, this could be a Poisson distribution where the variance and mean are both equal to the distribution parameter λ.

Comment: @ZahavaKor My statistics lecturers expected a hypothesis test when asking for a "test". I would assume OP should know from the lectures what the teacher means by "a variance test". But since they can't interpret their result I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure how a variance test determines that a data set is Poisson.

Nothing can really say that the data *are* drawn from a Poisson distribution, so the short answer is "it doesn't".

> How does a variance test show that a data set could be Poisson?

A very different question to the previous one.

What the closeness of the mean and the variance may tell you is that the data set is not inconsistent with having come from a Poisson distribution.

There are various ways, formal and informal, that you could try to see whather this is consistent.

An informal method would be to simulate data from Poisson distributions with means in the vicinity of 17.5 (I'd be inclined to investigate cases from say 10 to 30 or so) and see either how variable the sample mean and variance are (look at a plot) or how often the ratio of sample variance to sample mean differs from 1 by at least as much as you saw here at each value of $\mu$ you consider. (It will happen quite often.)

An even more informal one would be to simply recognize that the variation in the sample variance would be expected to be reasonably large -- more than several units with a parameter in this region and so considerable deviation might be expected -- but this requires some degree of experience with Poisson samples.

More formally you might choose a reasonable test statistic (perhaps that ratio mentioned just above) and investigate the properties of that.

A few quick simulations suggest that at your sample size the ratio (var/mean) is very close to the same shape with mean and variance that are pretty stable across a range of $\lambda$ values (I tried values of the Poisson parameter between 10 and 30), so it looks like it would be possible to obtain a good hypothesis test quite easily. A normal approximation to the cube root (or a gamma approximation to the ratio) would probably work quite well.

There are other potential test statistics; don't feel constrained by that one.

Comment: Could you explain for me what you meant by investigating cases from 10-30?

Comment: You don't know what the true Poisson parameter is. Your sample mean is 17.5 but many possible values of the Poisson parameter could produce a sample mean there. Consequently if you want to see whether your mean and variance could plausibly be that different you can't just say "well, what happens when $\lambda=17.5$?"... it may be that this much discrepancy doesn't happen all that often for some values of $\lambda$ that are consistent with $\bar{X}=17.5$, but does happen for others (though it depends on just what comparison between mean and variance you come up with). ... ctd

Comment: ctd... If it could easily happen at say $\lambda = 10,15,17.5,20,25,30$ ... it's not a conclusion that's sensitive to whatever the true value of $\lambda$ is. If you're familiar with the notion of a pivotal quantity and its use in hypothesis testing, the relevance of this concern when simulating may be clearer.